# What is the role of the South Korean military service in case of a war with North Korea

Tags: military, armed-conflict, north-korea, south-korea, conscription

South Korea is still officially at war with North Korea and Kim Jeong-Eun, the North Korean leader, regularly threatens to attack the South to various extents.

South Korea has a mandatory [military service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_South_Korea). In short,

1. All men, between the age of 18 and 35 years old, have to do their services for about 2 years.
2. After conscription, every man is automatically placed on reserve roster. Men have to attend yearly training and can be called to serve in the army in case of need.

**How would conscripts and reservists be mobilized and used in case of an active war between both Koreas**?

The possibility of war has been an important matter in South Korea for decades. Have the people (South Korean president/government and/or Commander in Chief of the Korean army) in charge of the military strategy against North Korea ever made any public statement about the role of military service?

Comment: I think it's generally understood in South Korea that the army (including conscripts) might have to fight North Korea one day. For obvious reasons, the details of South Korean military strategy will not be available to the public.

Comment: The role of any army is primarily self-defense. In terms of conscription, it is still a policy in countries such as Austria, Egypt and Turkey https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription#/media/File:Conscription_map_of_the_world.svg

Comment: Wait...is this actually Kim Jong-Un asking?

Comment: @blip: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/10/world/asia/north-korea-hack-war-plans.html   필요 없어 미국 바보... er... I mean... me and august leader of North Korea are different people!